# Javascript - Format date/time with moment.js

Tags: laravel, datetime, momentjs, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

Here i have used `Laravel:5.4` with `vue.js:2.x` and `moment.js`. I have used `moment` to display properly `date & time` in my `vue templates`.

For example, I have `2017-06-18` date in my database. So that i used:

```
{{ moment(bookingDetail.date).format('MMMM Do YYYY') }}, {{ moment(bookingDetail.date).format('dddd') }}
```

and this gave me result like: `June 18th 2017, Sunday`. This works seem fine.
Now, I also want to display time in my that vue template like:`01:00 pm`. I have `13:00:00` time in my database. I will tried for so like:

```
{{ moment(bookingDetail.time).format("h:mm a") }}
```

but this is not worked for me!

Is there anyone to help me? Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue myself using just add like:

```
{{ moment(bookingDetail.time, "HH:mm:ss").format("h:mm a") }}
```

The `moment` gives us full date & time if we have proper timestamp in our Database like if we have in our DB: `2017-06-16 15:07:00` then it's give us `June 16th 2017, Sunday @ 03:07 pm`. But if we want to get `03:07 pm` from in DB `15:07:00` then we need to do like:

```
{{ moment(bookingDetail.time, "HH:mm:ss").format("h:mm a") }}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) parsing function.

In the first case your input is in ISO 8601 format so it is recognized by [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), while in the second case you have to specify format.

In your case, you can use the following code:

```
{{ moment(bookingDetail.time, "HH:mm:ss").format("h:mm a") }}
```

Comment: Yes, i have fixed this! Anyways, thanks for your reply! This is works! :)